# In Python application, can't find where a item comes from

Tags: python, web2py

I'm trying to understand how web the framework **web2py** works, and there is this item called `request.client` in `access.py` that I can't figure out where it comes from. I retrieved the code from [here](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/0d646fa5e7c731cb5c392adf6a885351e77e4903/applications/admin/models/access.py) and it begins as follows:

```
import base64
import os
import time
from gluon.admin import apath
from gluon.fileutils import read_file
from gluon.utils import web2py_uuid
from pydal.contrib import portalocker
# ###########################################################
# ## make sure administrator is on localhost or https
# ###########################################################


http_host = request.env.http_host.split(':')[0]
```

My question is: when we don't know from where an item comes in a code, what is the method to find it out ?

Comment: Look at the library's documentation. Every legit library will have one.

Comment: did you try to call >>>help(request.client) ? you may find some useful info there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#API), web2py model, controller, and view files are executed by the framework in an environment that has already been populated with the core API objects, include `request`, `response`, `session`, `cache`, `DAL`, `Field`, HTML helpers, and form validators (other parts of the API, such Auth, Mail, Services, Scheduler, and many additional tools and contributed libraries, are contained in modules and imported as usual).

Specifically, the `request` object is created (upon each request) inside the main WSGI application ([gluon.main.wsgibase](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/e6a3081b42ecd58441419930266baf286561c4c7/gluon/main.py#L263)) at [this line](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/e6a3081b42ecd58441419930266baf286561c4c7/gluon/main.py#L293), and it is subsequently passed to [gluon.main.serve_controller](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/e6a3081b42ecd58441419930266baf286561c4c7/gluon/main.py#L148) at [this line](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/e6a3081b42ecd58441419930266baf286561c4c7/gluon/main.py#L442). The `serve_controller` function adds the `request` object to the execution environment and then executes model, controller, and view files in that environment.

In addition to model, controller, and view files, your application can include its own modules. Modules in applications are not executed by the framework (they must be imported) -- therefore, those modules must access the web2py core API objects via imports from `gluon` (the request-dependent objects, such as `request` and `response`, are accessed via the `current` thread-local object, as explained [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Sharing-the-global-scope-with-modules-using-the-current-object)).

It may also be helpful to review the [Workflow](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Workflow), [Libraries](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Libraries), and [Execution environment](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Execution-environment) sections of the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The file to which you link, `access.py`, mentions the name `request` for the first time on line 13:

```
http_host = request.env.http_host.split(':')[0]
```

This symbol, `request`, is not `import`ed from anywhere.  This is an unorthodox way of writing Python programs in general, and in isolation it looks impossible. But it *is* possible, if the symbol `request` was added to the global workspace of this file by some other file that wraps the execution of `access.py`. Here is a minimal example:

```
d = { 'request' : some_object() }
execfile( 'access.py', d )  # run the named file using d as its global workspace
```

So, in this particular case the way to investigate is to find the file that executes `access.py`.

[ In response to your comment about examining every file in the library: for such an analysis, and in general for a better quality of life as a programmer, you *will* need some tool that can search for a particular string in a whole hierarchy of files (like the command-line tool `grep` on Linux and MacOS,  or like many third-party text editors and IDEs on Windows, but ***not*** the perennially unreliable Windows "Search" function that claims to be able to do this). ]

In answer to your more general question about finding where things come from:  The other answers and comments mention attributes like `__file__` and/or `__module__`. These can help if you have a way of making your code spit out debug information.  Since you're working with a non-console (web) framework, that may be non-trivial, but one quick-and-dirty way might be to insert a line like this in `access.py`:

```
open('some_temporary_file_somewhere.txt', 'wt').write('\n'.join([
    repr( request ),
    request.__module__,
    request.__class__,
])
```

This should get you the details of where `request`'s class was defined (but not necessarily the name of the file in which the actual instance named `request` was created).

Answer (score 0):

When trying to figure out how an item has been imported into Python, you need to look at the explicit `import` statements in the file of interest. In well-written code, this will be obvious.

If you import the object of interest into a python shell, then you could use the `.__file__` attribute to find the bytecode file this object was imported from. There are other such attributes that you might find helpful, such as

```
.__name__
.__path__
.__package__
```

If you use IPython, which is highly recommended, you could easily get a list of these double underscore methods by typing in `<obj>.__` and hitting tab.

Looking at the file you linked, I am not sure where `request` was imported. `client`, though, is an attribute of the `request` object.

Comment: I'm sorry but your suggestions does not help me at all, I'm looking for a method which target the source of the item, I could inspect all libraries mentions in the imports, but that's not really smart, is it ?